# How to get the value of form input in dotnet core controller

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have view on which i have a product detail form

```
@model IEnumerable<Shop.Models.Product>

<form method="post" asp-controller="Product" asp-action="AddToCart">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="@item.Image" alt="Card image">
            <div class="card-body">
                <span class="card-title">@item.Name<b>: </b> </span>
                <b class="card-text">$@item.Price</b>
                <p class="card-text">@item.Description</p>
                <input type="number" min="1" max="10" class="form-control" value="1" placeholder="Please enter quantity" />
                <button asp-controller="Product" asp-action="AddToCart"
                   asp-route-ProductId="@item.ID"
                   asp-route-ProductName="@item.Name"
                   asp-route-ItemCount="1"
                   class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add to Cart</button>                        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Add to cart button is working as expected with default value. but now i want `asp-route-ItemCount="1"` to get value from text box i have but cant figure out the way on how to do this. I am learning dotnet thats why i dont want to use jquery ajax.

My product model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

A little help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of your problem in Microsoft docs. In table entity Product you must add an property.

```
 public int Count {get; set;}
```

Then you can change the text box:

```
<input asp-for="Product.Count" ..../>
```

And finally change the button:

```
 asp-route-ItemCount="@item.Count"
```

I think this a solution but for better understanding you can read this tutorial: 
[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)